# How to set time delay on emails php Mail()

Tags: php

this is my php script, is that possible to add some seconds time delay before the mail sends? For example, each time i use the contact form i want the mails to be sent after 20 seconds delay.

```
    <?php

// Debugging tools. Only turn these on in your development environment.

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");

// Special mail settings that can make mail less likely to be considered spam
// and offers logging in case of technical difficulties.

ini_set("mail.log", "/tmp/mail.log");
ini_set("mail.add_x_header", TRUE);

//variables
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Email']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = ''; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from example... contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@example.xyz \n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";  

if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)){ echo "Mail sent!";} else{ echo "Error, check your logs."; }
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

`mail` function is blocking in php. You cannot set the same in script. A better implementation would be to have a redis queue and push mail request on that queue. Once that is done you can have a worker node that parses the data from redis queue and uses the `mail` function in background. This way the script becomes non-blocking in nature.

There are other alternatives to redis like rabbitmq and zmq also.